# i always get error on the button part and getActivity. its my first time using fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

[image]

```
public class Supplier_Home extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Supplier_Home";
View view;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.s_1home, null);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.supply__home__po, container, false);
    Button pOrders=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.pOrders);
    pOrders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked login1.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You tagged javascript. This is Java.

Comment: If can paste the image of the code, then you can also post the code. Easier to you and easier for us to help you. By the way this is nothing to do with Android. It's **not reachable code** issue, if you return on previous line, how do you expect the compiler to process statements after the return.

Comment: @jennieka you are not pasing container object while inflating layouot and your are returning view  before creating it

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. The first line of your method is the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the complete view in the starting itself making the code below return unreachable.

You have given two layouts, If I am not wrong s_1home is layout of your activity where view pager is resting and supply__home__po is your fragment layout. Considering my assumptions are correct please change the code as follows

```
public class Supplier_Home extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "Supplier_Home";
View view;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.supply__home__po, container, false);
    Button pOrders=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.pOrders);
    pOrders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Clicked login1.");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
    }
    });
   return view;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like, Create View object like this. Pass container object while inflating layout

```
View view;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashbord, container, false);
    Button btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn)

 return view;
}
```